# How to customize nginx error log lines (omit datetime and severity)?

Tags: nginx, logging

I have configured my nginx server's error log as follows:

```
error_log syslog:server=unix:/dev/log,nohostname,tag= notice;
```

This results in the following type of log lines (in systemd journal):

```
apr 11 22:54:37 hostname [616892]: 2020/04/11 22:54:37 [notice] 616892#0: using the "epoll" event method
apr 11 22:54:37 hostname [616892]: 2020/04/11 22:54:37 [notice] 616892#0: nginx/1.16.1
apr 11 22:54:37 hostname [616892]: 2020/04/11 22:54:37 [notice] 616892#0: OS: Linux 5.4.28
apr 11 22:54:37 hostname [616892]: 2020/04/11 22:54:37 [notice] 616892#0: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1024:524288
apr 11 22:54:37 hostname [616893]: 2020/04/11 22:54:37 [notice] 616893#0: start worker processes
apr 11 22:54:37 hostname [616893]: 2020/04/11 22:54:37 [notice] 616893#0: start worker process 616895
```

Everything before the first colon (`apr 11 22:54:37 hostname [616892]` in the example) is from the OS's logging system (systemd journal) and what follows is provided by nginx (e.g., `2020/04/11 22:54:37 [notice] 616892#0: nginx/1.16.1`). As you can see, nginx provides the date and also the severity (`notice` in the example). Both are captured already by the OS's logging system. Therefore, I would like to instruct nginx to not add this information (`2020/04/11 22:54:37 [notice]`) to the log lines. However, I have not found out whether this is possible and then how. I know that the `log_format` directive exists, but it applies only to the access log, AFAIK.)

Therefore, **is it possible to customize the error log lines generated by nginx?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the `date [level] pid#tid message` log pattern (i.e. everything you find after the first colon `:`) is hardcoded into **Nginx** (cf. the [source code](https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/b82c08f6102d65a5e5902e6fa85082e184a75003/src/core/ngx_log.c#L117)). You won't be able to change it through configuration, you need to recompile the server.

What you can change (and you are already doing it) is only the **syslog** metadata:

- you can toggle off sending the hostname name with `nohostname`,
- you can change the `SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER` with the `tag=identifier` option,

and that's all.

Answer (score 2):

You have already answered your own question. You can't customize the error log format, only the access log format as per [Log Module Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html)

For the error log you can only change logging level

Comment: I'm still hoping that there is some undocumented way…